# Create block of content?

Tags: php, html, css, drupal, drupal-blocks

How can I create a simple block of content, similar to the "Unrest in the Middle East" section on [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/)?

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you comfortable with creating your own module? What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: i use drupal 6

i want create block with last node from term and show one image from last node term ,similar to the "Unrest in the Middle East" section on The Economist?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Views will allow you to do this.
http://drupal.org/project/views

Simply create a block view that queries the specific node term you desire. From there you can specify to only display titles, show an image from the latest post, limit the number of titles displayed, etc...

Views will take some learning though. I'd highly recommend lullabot's tutorials.

Comment: thank you for answer my problem is i dont know who to create show an image from the last post

Comment: You could use CCK to add a custom text field to each piece of content for that type that specifies the URL to the image you want to display. CCK is another module that will require a little bit of learning, but once you understand views and cck you'll be able to do what you've described fairly simply.

Comment: ok im work with cck and views and any modules drupal but i dont know how to create filter for query from latest image from title

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem  you are running into. Could you please rephrase your problem?